# Minimizing rounding error on calculation of Complex Atanh

Tags: algorithms, complex-numbers

I am trying to implement the calculation of the complex inverse tangens hyperbolicus function in my program in VB.NET. I am using the formula  : $\arctan(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}  {\rm Log}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$. This works but when checking the result against Mathematica I notice rounding errors (I'm using double precision).
So for example $\arctan(54+ 63 i)$ I get with my implementation:

$$0.00784264136408108 + 1.56164569254476i$$

versus the correct result

$$0.00784264136408112(65) + 1.56164569254476(05771)i$$

As you can see, the real part of the result is somewhat wrong due to rounding errors. I already tried writing the fraction as difference between two logarithms, pull the 0.5* into the logarithm, but it all gives not really a lot of precision. Now I would like to know how this function is usually implemented to avoid rounding errors as best as possible. Thank you.

Addition: My implementation of Complex.Log

> If Input.Real > 0 Then Result.Imaginary = Atan(Input.Imaginary / Input.Real)
>   If Input.Real < 0 Then
>   {
>     If Input.Imaginary >= 0 Then Result.Imaginary = PI + Atan(Input.Imaginary / Input.Real)
>     If Input.Imaginary < 0 Then Result.Imaginary = -PI + Atan(Input.Imaginary / Input.Real)
>   }
>   If Input.Real = 0 Then
>   {
>     If Input.Imaginary > 0 Then Result.Imaginary = PI / 2
>     If Input.Imaginary <= 0 Then Result.Imaginary = -PI / 2
>   }
>   Result.Real = 0.5 * Log(Input.Real^2 + Input.Imaginary^2)
>   Return Result.Real + i*Result.Imaginary

Comment: 1) What is your algorithm?  2) What makes you think Mathematica is correct?

Comment: Have you tried Lorentz expansion? By putting as many terms as you want, you can control the rounding error.

Comment: I use Mathematica as a point of reference due to it offering calculations more precise than standard double-precision in my opinion. My algorithm is basically just what I wrote above but I will edit my implementation of Complex.Log in for good measure. I don't know what Lorentz Expansion is so I will have to read up on that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a computer expert but doesn't double precision only give you 16 digits of accuracy? Which easily explains the difference. Lorentz expansion is a complex version of Taylor expansion.

Comment: You could do worse than use the algorithm described by Kahan in his 'Much ado about nothing's sign bit' paper:  http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf

Comment: It's a precision to 15-16 digits (15.9 or something) but it's these digits + an exponent. So you can represent a number of 1.53251412427534*10^-153. The inaccuary in my result is at digit 14. I might be to cranky about this since even the implementation in the C++ Standard library doesn't match any more precisely with Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a pretty good result to me:  you're out only by a handful of ULPs (units in the last place) in the real part.  You probably can't hope to do that much better without resorting to a *much* more sophisticated algorithm---for example, using extended precision for the intermediate computations and then rounding back to double precision, or using different polynomial or rational approximations for different regions of the complex plane.

That said, there's a [classic reference](http://people.freebsd.org/~das/kahan86branch.pdf) from Kahan on the subject of implementing the basic complex functions, including `atanh`.  You might also take a look at Python's implementation [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/cmathmodule.c#L305).  I believe this is about as much as you can reasonably do with a straightforward double-precision based algorithm.  (Disclaimer:  I wrote the Python implementation, so I'm biased.)  In this particular case, it gives this result:

```
>>> from cmath import atanh
>>> atanh(54+63j)
(0.007842641364081127+1.5616456925447606j)
```

which turns out to be the closest complex number representable in double-precision to the exact result (so has an error of less than 0.5 ulps in both the real and imaginary part).

Comment: I used the implementation from Kahan and it's working great. It's basically as precise as it can get with double, possibly due to eliminating the need to calculate the Complex logarithm on the way. Great paper.

Comment: @Jens: Out of curiosity, does VB.Net have a `log1p` function?  You'll probably need that to get accurate results everywhere.

Comment: Not that I know of. But as I understand it it's just an if/else statement that calculates the logarithm as a 2 term Taylor series for small x values.

Comment: Well, there's a sneaky trick for `log1p` that tends to work better than using a Taylor polynomial for small values, but relies on IEEE 754 semantics being followed exactly.  You compute `y = 1 + x`, then compute the result as `log(y) - ((y - 1) - x)/y`.  The second term corrects for the difference between the true value of `1 + x` and the nearest representable double `y`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that implementation explains the differences I had between the Python/C++ implementation and my own.